# Hadoop startup time for multiple runs

Tags: hadoop

I have a hadoop job fat jar which is used to run the job with different parameters regularly multiple times. The startup time seems to be very high for each job. My guess is that the fat jar gets transferred to the task tracker each time. I dont want to add the job jar to each classpath manually. Is it possible to transfer the entire job jar to dist cache once and run it multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

The `distributed cache` you mentioned, is nothing else than copying your `JAR` to all tasktrackers.

What you can do, if your fat-jar is not changed too often, is putting the jar into the lib folder of Hadoop. These will be included with every job run.

Comment: Thats what i have been thinking and have that as a lost shot. But i just want to know if there are any better way to handle that